Hölder stability of the PDE $\partial_t u (t, x) = \operatorname{div} \{ a (t, x) \nabla u(t, x) \}$
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\qtext}[1]{\quad\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\qtextq}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\trace}{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Div}{div}
$
We fix $T \in (0, \infty)$ and let $\bT$ be the interval $[0, T]$. We consider the measurable function
\begin{align}
\sigma &: \bT \times \bR^d \to \bR^d \otimes \bR^m .
\end{align}
Let $a := \sigma \sigma^\top$. We denote

$\sigma_t := \sigma (t, \cdot)$ and $a_t := a (t, \cdot)$.
by $\nabla$ the gradient operator w.r.t space variable.
by $\partial_t$ the derivative w.r.t time.

We fix $\alpha \in (0, 1)$. We assume there exists a constant $C >0$ such that for $t \in \bT$ and $x, y \in \bR^d$:

$a_t$ is invertible and $\sigma_t$ is differentiable.
$\frac{|\nabla \sigma_t (x) - \nabla \sigma_t (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} + | \nabla \sigma_t (x) | + | \sigma_t (x) | + | a_t^{-1} (x) |  \le C$.

We fix a probability density function $f : \bR^d \to \bR_+$ such that
$$
\|f \|_{C^\alpha_b} := \| f \|_\infty + \sup_{x, y \in \bR^d; x \neq y} \frac{|f (x) - f (y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} \le C.
$$
Let $u : \mathbb T \times \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R_+$ be the distributional solution to the Cauchy problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u (t, x) &= \Div \{ a (t, x) \nabla u(t, x) \} , \\
u(0, \cdot) &= f .
\end{cases}
$$
I wonder if there exists a constant $c$ (depending only on $\alpha, C, T, d$) such that
$$
\sup_{t \in \bT} \| u(t, \cdot) \|_{C^\alpha_b} \le c \|f \|_{C^\alpha_b} .
$$
Thank you very much for your elaboration. Any reference is greatly appreciated.
